# admin login screen is not working with mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My admin log in screen is not working even if I put in the right password and user name that is in the database it just doesn't seem to like it can anyone help fix my problem here is my code for the admin login

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('../config/dbconn.php');
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

        $user_unsafe=$_POST['username'];
        $pass_unsafe=$_POST['password'];

        $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn,$user_unsafe);
        $pass1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn,$pass_unsafe);

        $pass=md5($pass1);
        $salt="a1Bz20ydqelm8m1wql";
        $pass=$salt.$pass;


        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


        $query=mysqli_query($dbconn,"SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'");
        $res=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $id=$res['user_id'];

        if (mysqli_num_rows($query)<1){
            $_SESSION['msg']="Login Failed, User not found!";
            header('Location:admin_login_page.php');
        }

        else{
            $res=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            $_SESSION['id']=$res['user_id'];
            header('Location: admin_index.php');

            $_SESSION['id']=$id;
            $remarks="has logged in the system at ";
            mysqli_query($dbconn,"INSERT INTO logs(user_id,action,date) VALUES('$id','$remarks','$date')")or die(mysqli_error($dbconn));
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: `$pass=md5($pass1);` NO. Noooooooo. No no no. Read the *big red box* on http://php.net/md5, then use http://php.net/password_hash.

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? It gives you "Login failed. User not found!"?

Comment: yes i just says log in failed even if i type in the correct username and password.

Comment: Can I have a loook at dbconn.php?

Comment: <?php
$dbconn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","partsbuyer");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
?>

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: above is the dbconn code but i used the same code that i have listed as the question as my user log in and it works fine but it just not wroking when it comes to the admin part

Comment: Unless this is strictly for academic/learning purposes, don't fix it. This code cannot be trusted to actually secure anything, it's got several critical problems that are not easily fixed because of fundamental flaws in this approach. What's your intent with this code? Is it to protect something, or just to explore and learn?

Comment: it  is just for educational purposes am just experimenting with php and trying to see what i can make just need help with this bit

Comment: I just need someone’s help on how I can fix my problem

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `mysqli_fetch_array` twice - once before the `if` and once in the `else` block. Since the query should return at most one row, the second fetching will fail.

As a side note, you should not use string manipulation when constructing an SQL query, as you'll leave your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should consider using a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: can you tell me how would i fix it